# How to deal with "javac: directory not found: classes" in Windows 8

Tags: java, compilation

I have installed Java compiler on my Windows laptop, and tried to run a complier with:

```
echo off
javac 2> errors -classpath classes -sourcepath src -d classes src\Quasitiler\*.java
type errors
```

But there was an error message:

> javac: directory not found: classes
>   Usage: javac  
>   use -help for a list of possible options

How should I proceed with this? It is for `QuasiTiler`, a small program downloaded for creating figures.

Comment: Create the missing classes directory? `mkdir classes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run javac from within src directory; so java program with correct package is available for compilation

Ex:

```
Source Dir: D:\~\JavaSamples\src

Classes Dir: D:\~\JavaSamples\classes

So when you try compiling from src directory as below, classes will be compiled:

D:\~\JavaSamples\src>javac -classpath ../classes -d ../classes com\library\model\MovieDAO.java
```